# Parametric Apache Virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, wildcard

I have a Virtualhost made this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Servername www.website.com
        DocumentRoot /path/to/application-1.2.1/client/app/
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/logs/application.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Where `application` is the application name that changes everytime we deploy a new version, so for example next DocumentRoot would be:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/application-1.2.2/client/app/
```

Is it possible to make a virtualhost with a wildcard or something like:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/application-*/client/app/
```

So that I don't have to change the virtualhost everytime I deploy a new version of the application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't have a wildcard there.

Instead, use symlinks:

```
ln -s /path/to/application-1.2.2/client/app /path/to/application/client/app
```

and have the config read

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Servername www.website.com
        DocumentRoot /path/to/application/client/app/
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/logs/application.log
</VirtualHost>
```

This has the added bonus that you can keep the old version around for a fast rollback when needed.

Depending on your main configuration, you may need to add

```
    <Directory /path/to/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>
```

to your config, as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is actually required for a DocumentRoot but most default configurations have the following of symbolic links disabled and you might need a     `<Directory /path/to/>  Options +FollowSymlinks  </Directory>`  in the virtualhost entry.

Comment: @HBruijn Good catch, I added this to my response.